# Problems with understanding newcolumntype

Tags: tables

I am trying to define my own column type and am running in to a misplaced noalign error when using it at the end of a table. I figured out a way to circumvent this using multicolumns, but am still interested in knowing what I am doing wrong. I made a minimal code example:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper,twoside]{article}

\usepackage{array}


\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}


\begin{document}

 \begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{ | C{2cm} | C{2cm} | }
   \hline

   \textbf{foo} &\multicolumn{1}{C{1cm}|}{bar}   \\ %works
   %\textbf{foo} & bar   \\ % doesnt work
   \hline
  \end{tabular}

 \end{table}
\end{document}
```

I would be grateful for any insight in what might be the problem here.

Comment: you need `\arraybackslash` after `\centering` (or use `\tabularnewline` rather than `\\ ` to end the row. `\centering` redefines `\\ ` to make a centred newline, so breaks its use to end the table row unless you use `\arraybackslash` to redefine it back again.